# Change dovecot user password

Tags: node.js, cryptojs, dovecot

I am using dovecot and configured it to load User accounts from a mySQL Table.
This is my configuration:

```
driver=mysql
connect = "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=vmail user=vmail password=verySecret"
default_pass_scheme = SHA512-CRYPT

password_query = SELECT username AS user, domain, password FROM accounts WHERE username = '%n' AND domain = '%d' and enabled = true;
user_query = SELECT concat('*:storage=', quota, 'M') AS quota_rule FROM accounts WHERE username = '%n' AND domain = '%d' AND sendonly = false;
iterate_query = SELECT username, domain FROM accounts where sendonly = false;
```

I have a small nodejs application for user administration. But I can't generate the passowrds. I try to use crypto libraray in node, but the user is not able to login.
When I create a password via doveadm the user ist able to login.

What to do, do set a passwort from a nodejs application?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a database a `mySQL` driver and using a `SHA512-CRYPT` hash to control users and passwords, so you need to encrypt the password with `doveadm` tool.

```sh
root@none:~# doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT 
Enter new password: 
Retype new password: 
{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$jS4C7A0o3/roDu8C$cbOHg5Vg6WJKBi/DL2JM7Th4W1LW86RjTTLlwWJa7w7fbKCkLGX0Jl.hGKBFmz3/a1xxYVbO6lc9nF6e26vVe/
```

then all you need is go inside your database and `UPDATE` the contents of the password to the correct user.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was how to do this in NodeJS, not with `doveadm` on the command line.